# Is it possible the pre-order traversal be the same order as the post-order traversal?

Tags: graph-theory, tree-traversal, preorder, postorder

If T be an ordered tree with more than one node. Is it possible the pre-order traversal of T visit the nodes in the same order as the post-order traversal of T?
if "yes" can you please give an example. And if "No" could you please explain why it cannot occur?

Comment: Do you have a hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

In general cases, the leaves of a tree are unique, and as such, should appear in opposite manners if you're performing a pre- or post-order traversal.

However, I can see two cases in which the pre- and post-order traversals are the same:  Singleton and duplicate elements.

With a singleton, you only have the one node, so it doesn't matter if you visit it before or after looking for zero leaves.

What if you had a tree with duplicate elements in it?  If the insertion strategy was to accept any element greater than or equal to the root node, then they would appear as a degenerate tree to the right:

```
 A
  \
   A
    \
     A
      \
       A
```

If it were less than or equal to the root node, you'd still have a degenerate tree, but to the left.

Now, if your insertion strategy was to discard duplicate elements, you would be left with the singleton case, which still has the pre- and post-order traversals resulting in the same elements.

Comment: Thank you, 
Sorry I cannot vote for you both.
So if we have three same elements: A1     A2     A3;
Pre-order:    A1     A2    A3;
Post-order:   A3      A2     A1; both are same

Comment: The value retrieved from the node will be the same but you are visiting different nodes to obtain the values. It depends on what use do you want your tree to be for

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something painfully obvious, the answer would be no. A ordered tree with > 1 node (say for example, 2 nodes) will look like this.

> ```
>     A    
>  B
> ```

or

> ```
>     A
>         C
> ```

Post-order traversal visits the nodes in the order left-right-root and pre-order visits the nodes in the order of root-left-right. In order for them to produce the same output, "left" must be equals to "root", which just doesn't make sense. With the above example, pre-order will produce AB or AC respectively and post-order will produce BA and CA.

Comment: Thank you,
So just in one situation the pre-order and post-order are the same. just if "left or right" is equals to "root"? is there any other exception?

Comment: left will be equals to root only if there is one node